# How do I correctly instantiate a public class+data structure in a class so that other objects can use it?

Tags: java, constructor, null, nullpointerexception

In my code, I have a seperate Runner class that instantiates a World, which has a 4x4 array of Locations (a separate class) stored as a Location[][] array. When I print/try to use the Location array, its value is null, and it throws a NullPointerException.

```
public class Runner 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
...
WumpusWorld test_loc = new WumpusWorld();
System.out.print(test_loc) //This prints an ID for the WumpusWorld object
System.out.print(test_loc.world) //Null value prints here
//I'd like to pass the test_loc.world values to an actor here
...
}
}
```

The applicable code for the WumpusWorld is as follows:

```
public class WumpusWorld 
{
public Location[][] world;
public WumpusWorld()
{
    new WumpusWorld((byte) 4); //this constructor is used
}
...
public WumpusWorld(byte size)
{
this.world = new Location[size][size];
for(byte i = 0; i<size; i++)
{
    for(byte j = 0;j<size;j++)
    {
    world[i][j] = new Location(j,i,true,false,false);
    }
    //Location instances called in the form world[x][y]
    //are error free in constructor
...
}
}
```

Comment: Looks correct to me - is `world` being reassigned somewhere else? You'll need to include more code because the issue isn't here.

Comment: @Paul Bellora I added the other constructor in my last edit, which was causing the problem I believe. I switched to the (now 2nd) constructor, and the program ran without error. Eclipse shows no error, but I don't understand what (if anything shown) would mess it up.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in you constructor with parameter after those 2 for-loops and tell me what the world[][] contains

Comment: @Hitman it is showing two WumpusWorlds constructed, I think that is my problem. One has the locations array instantiated properly and the other has a null value for world[][].

Comment: Exactly :). Good luck in future :)

Comment: @WilBur This is where it would help to declare `world` as `final`, because you would get an error that the first constructor wasn't initializing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem might be in the way you call `public WumpusWorld(byte size)` from the default constructor.

Try this:

```
public WumpusWorld()
{
    this((byte) 4);
}
```

With `new` in the call, I had uninitialized values in the inner class